# Copying/Backing up (i.e. cloning) files from Windows 11 every hour into Backup drive

Tags: windows, backup

I want to clone the Windows NVMe drive into the HDD long term storage drives every hour without placing files in "backups" folder. It must be like "Backup (B:)\Windows 11\clone-of-windows drive root".

Can this be done using windows backup, or do I need a custom batch script?